# What is this Query? and why its taking too much time? Any way to optimize it?

Tags: taxonomy, query

Query:

```
SELECT  t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('post_tag') AND tt.count > 0 ORDER BY t.name ASC;
```

**Query_time: 3.445370**

Comment: How many tags do you have?

Comment: Almost 55,470 tags

Comment: Well that’s why. Not much you can do to optimise a query for 50k+ records. Where is this query coming from?

Comment: @JacobPeattie that's the issue. checked my theme code, it's not there. But running timely on the server.

Comment: I can find several such SQL statements, originating from `wp-includes/class-wp-term.php`, `wp-includes/class-wp-term-query.php` and `wp-includes/taxonomy.php` in a 5.0.3 installation of WP.

Comment: @Jos How to get rid of this? if don't want to use tags anymore...